# Periodical structure and non-periodic element

Tags: comsol

Is it possible to make a geometry in Comsol that combines a periodically repeating structure and one non-periodic element? Like in this figure:

[image: periodically repeating structure and one non-periodic element]

Answer (score 1):

The answer is NO. I just got it from a Comsol official.